# why need to first use node scrip.js before loading into browser

Tags: node.js, setup-project

I am at learning stage of `node.js`.

I need to know why i need to use `node script.js` `command` line to be execute first in `cmd` before see actual result on browser?

I have installed `node.msi` setup in my computer i also have `wamp` server running.

can anyone guide me what are this and how can i run it directly without using `CMD` code.

`Node.js` looks awesome but how can i make it run on live server too?

I have installed `mysql` module and after 20-25 minutes of googling i make it run but i can not access it directly on browser i need to run it first from `CMD`.

is it possible that i can run node js without having install it using setup of exe file.?

Thanks

Comment: @dipesh-parmar It is really not related. node.js is a standalone framework. It doesn't require, not cross way, with php. You need to run your script.js as a standalone server (like Apache) and connect to mysql itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

node.js installs as a standalone executable, unlike WAMP where the Apache server is installed as a Windows service. As the comments suggest, node.js has nothing to do with your current WAMP installation.

This gives you flexibility of serving multiple instances of the application on the same machine (with load balancing front-end of course).
You can make your node app run as service with [`winser`](https://npmjs.org/package/winser) package.

I've not yet successfully done so though.